# How to use a logical Add operator in element-wise in Microsoft.Data.Analysis

Tags: c#, dataframe, logical-operators, elementwise-operations

I want to use a logical Add operator in element-wise in Microsoft.Data.Analysis to filter some elements,but no method I have found, my code is below.

My aim is find out all elements that logical And 1 > 0 in col1( element & 1 > 0), of course, the code does not work, the method ElementwiseLogicalAnd does not exist.

I cannot find samples or any documentation is MS office net, so how to do it?

```
PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<bool> filterIndx = df.Columns["col1"].ElementwiseLogicalAnd(read);
DataFrame newdf = df.Filter(filterIndx);
```